# Why I am getting pylint error in Django blog? How to solve this issue? Installed pylint. Using VSC Mac

Tags: django, pylint

I am a beginner in **Django**, I am trying to build a basic app by referring a tutorial, after completed the code, getting lots of error related to **pylint**.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank you.

[These are the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PN98.png)

Answer (score 0):

A linter provides you with warnings to help you improve your code or when there are conventional ways of doing things but those are not errors.

Comment: okay. thank you. but when I try to run the server, its not working.

Comment: Could you provide more information, what is it you are trying to run, is there any output when you try to run it.